# How to use exported struct in JS file?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I have the following definitions in the Rust code:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Point {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point { x, y }
    }
}
```

I logged the created object in JS file:

```
let p = new Point(23, 34);
console.log(p);
```

But it's giving me a pointer value with the prototype, I don't know how to use it.

[image]

How can I get a JS object like { x: 23, y: 34 } with the prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `wasm_bindgen` doesn't include the actual fields of structs when passing them to JS, instead generating a wrapper object that simply has a pointer to the data on the (WASM) heap and exposes the methods/properties using the prototype. You should be able to access (public) fields and invoke methods using standard JS syntax, as shown [here in the wasm-bindgen reference](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/exported-rust-types.html).

If you really want to pass the actual contents back, you can use [`JsValue::from_serde`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/0.2/wasm_bindgen/struct.JsValue.html#method.from_serde), which allows serializing any type that implements `Serialize` into a JS object. Note that this object will not expose the methods, however - it's intended for passing plain data across the JS/WASM boundary. This is documented [here in the wasm-bindgen reference](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/arbitrary-data-with-serde.html).